# Varnish 3.0 returns 503 intermittently even though backend server responds in under 3 seconds

Tags: tcp, varnish, f5, big-ip

We are experiencing a weird problem with Varnish 3.0.  We are observing a rate of 10-20 failures per node per minute in our varnish farm.  Varnish talks to a backend server which is fronted by a load balancer application (F5) in this case.  We took TCP dumps on the Varnish layer and the load balancer layer.  It appears that the backend server is responding in around 3 seconds.  In the TCP dump we see the 200 Ok being received by Varnish after 3 seconds.  After this is where we see the strange behaviour.  Varnish server sends the ACK message to the load balancer within milliseconds.  The FIN, ACK message is sent after a delay of about 10 seconds.  This time matches the 10 second  configuration in the Varnish layer and we see the 503 error being returned from the Varnish layer.    This is the Varnish backend configuration.  The backend has been renamed due to security reasons.

```
    backend backend1{
        .host = "<load balancer virtual server name>"; 
        .port = "<port>";
        .first_byte_timeout     = 120s;    
        .connect_timeout        = 10s;     
        .between_bytes_timeout  = 10s;     
    }
```

Have any of you experienced a similar issue.  Any pointers on troubleshooting this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the `between_bytes_timeout` configuration. You have set it to be 10 seconds, and according to you, the load balancer takes 10 seconds to send the FIN, ACK message. 
From the [varnish docs](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/varnishd.html):

> between_bytes_timeout
>      Units: s
>      Default: 60
>
> Default timeout between bytes when receiving data from backend. We only wait for this many seconds between bytes before giving up. A value of 0 means it will never time out. VCL can override this default value for each backend request and backend request. This parameter does not apply to pipe.

Try to increase this number and see what happens